# React native: Error: Rendered [more/less] hooks than during the previous render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I created a top sticky bar to display tabs for different categories of products. The bar will appear and disappear depending on how far down the screen the user is and it will also change the tab indicator according to what category is being displayed.

It works fine and dandy. Except for when the user pulls down the screen to refresh/update the data and the number of category changes. When this happens the app crashes with this error:

```
Error: Rendered more** hooks than during the previous render.
```

** If the new data has less "tabs" then the error shows less and not more.

I know where the error is coming from, I just don't know how to fix it. It comes from creating `refs` for each tab using `useRef()` hook. When the app re-renders (due to a data refresh) and the number of hooks changes and it crashes. Is there a way to destroy the previous refs? I am out of ideas and any suggestion is highly appreciated.

**Tabs.js - Function component**

```
const Tabs = ({ tabs, tabIndex, show, onPress }) => {
    const tabsContainerRef = useRef(null);
    const tabsScrollViewRef = useRef(null);
    const indicatorRef = useRef(null);

    const translateY = useRef(new Animated.Value(-100)).current;
    const translateX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const indicatorWidth = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;

    const [hasLoaded, setHasLoaded] = useState(false);

    // THIS IS CAUSING THE ERROR !
    tabs = tabs.map((tab) => {
        return { ...tab, ref: useRef() };
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!hasLoaded) {
            setHasLoaded(true);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (hasLoaded) {
            tabs[0].ref?.current.measure((x, y, width, height) => {
            Animated.timing(indicatorWidth, {
                toValue: width,
                duration: 250,
                useNativeDriver: false,
            }).start();
            });
        }
    }, [hasLoaded]);

    useEffect(() => {
        Animated.timing(translateY, {
            toValue: show ? 0 : -100,
            duration: 250,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();
    }, [show]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (show) {
            tabs[tabIndex].ref?.current.measureLayout(
                tabsScrollViewRef.current,
                (x, y, width, height) => {
                // console.log(x, y, width, height);
                Animated.timing(indicatorWidth, {
                    toValue: width,
                    duration: 250,
                    useNativeDriver: false,
                }).start();

                Animated.timing(translateX, {
                    toValue: x,
                    duration: 250,
                    useNativeDriver: false,
                }).start();

                tabs[tabIndex].ref?.current.measure(
                    (tabX, tabY, tabWidth, tabHeight, tabPageX, tabPageY) => {
                    // console.log(tabX, tabY, tabWidth, tabHeight, tabPageX, tabPageY);
                    if (tabPageX < 0 || tabPageX > SCREEN_WIDTH)
                        tabsScrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({
                        x,
                        animated: true,
                        });
                    }
                );
                },
                (error) => {
                console.log("Failed to track tab indicator: ", error);
                }
            );
            }
        }, 250);
    }, [tabIndex]);

    return (
        <Animated.View
            ref={tabsContainerRef}
            style={[
            styles.containerTabs,
            {
                transform: [{ translateY }],
            },
            ]}
        >
            <ScrollView
            ref={tabsScrollViewRef}
            style={styles.containerTabsScrollView}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.contentTabsScrollView}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            horizontal
            >
            {tabs.map((tab, index) => {
                return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    ref={tab.ref}
                    key={index}
                    onPress={() => onPress(index)}
                    style={styles.containerTab}
                >
                    <Animated.View
                    style={
                        tabIndex === index
                        ? [styles.containerTabContent, { opacity: 1 }]
                        : styles.containerTabContent
                    }
                    >
                    <Text style={styles.textTab}>{tab.title}</Text>
                    </Animated.View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                );
            })}

            <Animated.View
                ref={indicatorRef}
                style={{
                height: 5,
                backgroundColor: ClientConfig.colors.primary,
                position: "absolute",
                bottom: 0,
                width: indicatorWidth,
                transform: [{ translateX }],
                }}
            ></Animated.View>
            </ScrollView>
        </Animated.View>
    );
};
```

**Additional inquiry**

The component that calls my component `Tabs` is a Class component type, could I create the tab references with it (using `React.createRef()`), send it to my Tabs (Function component) and use it there? I tried to send the `refs` with the tabs data through props and React didn't like it.

Thank you.

Comment: Would it make a difference if I made it a Class component?? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials I found a solution. All I had to do was make sure the component was unmounted on the refresh of data so all hooks would be cleaned up by React. So Where I called the component `Tabs` I added a conditional statement `!refreshing` like so:

```
{!refreshing && tabs.length && (
    <Tabs
        tabs={tabs}
        tabIndex={tabIndex}
        show={showTabs}
        onPress={this.onTabPress}
    />
)}
```

This took care of the issue finally :). The code above for the Tabs needed some fine tuning after this change, the indicator width is not being set after the refresh but that's ok, easy fix.